# Will my two installations of MySQL conflict?

Tags: php, mysql, macos

I have OS X 10.5.8 Leopard with developer tools, so it has mysql already installed in /usr/local/mysql. However, now I am going to use MacPorts to install my own MAMP stack instead of using the built-in one, so that I can have PHP 5.3. Do I need to reinstall MySQL using port? If so, how do I disable the old installation of MySQL so that they don't conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your existing MySQL installation. Of course you can run two instances. Just make sure they don't interfere in the port and/or socket configuration.

If you want to remove the existing installation, read [this](http://tomkeur.net/39/how-to-remove-mysql-completely-mac-os-x-leopard.html) guide.